# Set Folder Permissions for 2 users 1 folder

Tags: file, file-permissions, explorer, user-permissions, windows-server-2019

I need help setting permissions to \XDRIVE\Share for 2 users.

Example:

UserA - can only read, write, and modify its own files, restricted from UserB files
UserB - can only read, write, and modify its own files, restricted from UserA files

I shared the folder to the 2 users, provided it with read, write, permissions. I included CREATOR OWNER into the permissions. I even created a document from UserA and for some reason I could delete it from UserB account.